# Disable all inputs in row where one input value is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through a table and get the value of an input in a specific row.  If that value is `0` disable all the inputs in that row.

Here's my latest unsuccessful attempt.

```
$('.hiderow-0 input[id*="Quantity"]').each(function() {
   if($(this ).val() == 0){
     $(this).closest('tr').find("input,button,textarea").attr('disabled',true);
    }

 });
```

Example HTML

```
<table>
<tr class='hiderow-0'><td><select name="data[TransactionItem][0][quantity]" id="TransactionItem0Quantity">
<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select></td>
<td><input name="data[TransactionItem][0][note]" value=""  maxlength="100" type="text" id="TransactionItem0Note"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[TransactionItem][0][waitlisted]"  class="waitlisted" options="0 1" value="1" id="TransactionItem0Waitlisted"/>    
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please expand your example with the html? Be aware that you can post snipplets that work within the site. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it after I used *select* instead of *input*

```js
 $('.hiderow-0 select[id*="Quantity"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 0){ 
    $(this).closest('tr').find("input,select").attr('disabled',true);
 
  }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class='hiderow-0'><td><select name="data[TransactionItem][0][quantity]" id="TransactionItem0Quantity">
<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select></td>
<td><input name="data[TransactionItem][0][note]" value=""  maxlength="100" type="text" id="TransactionItem0Note"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[TransactionItem][0][waitlisted]"  class="waitlisted" options="0 1" value="1" id="TransactionItem0Waitlisted"/>    
</td></tr>
  <tr class='hiderow-0'><td><select name="data[TransactionItem][1][quantity]" id="TransactionItem1Quantity">
<option value="0" >0</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select></td>
<td><input name="data[TransactionItem][1][note]" value=""  maxlength="100" type="text" id="TransactionItem0Note"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[TransactionItem][1][waitlisted]"  class="waitlisted" options="0 1" value="1" id="TransactionItem0Waitlisted"/>    
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(this).closest("tr:input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `.prop('disabled', true)`. `.attr()` changes the HTML attribute. [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)